# How to save data between calls to a IHttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, web-services

I have a IHttpHandler that acts as a source to a jQuery Autocomplete input field. In the constructor of the handler I generate an index that remains fairly static between request (needs to be rebuilt maybe once a day).

How can I cache the the index between calls? Debugging indicates that the constructor is called for each request. I've set IsReusable to "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler is passed an `HttpContext` which means it has access to the application cache (e.g. `context.Cache["Foo"] = myVal`) and can save values there. However, you can also save the value in Session (e.g. `context.Session["Bar"]`) if your handler implements the IRequiresSessionState interface.

Answer (score 1):

HttpHandlers have a special propert **[IsReusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx)**. You can override that property in your Handler implementation and set it to return True. **IsReusable is a value indicating whether another request can use the IHttpHandler instance.**

So **first time when the handler is accessed the Handler instance is created and upon next request the same instance serves the request back** - so your caching trick will work right in this case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx